# How to express $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$ in terms of $\cos(\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

There are plenty of formulae for half-angles, double angles, but I haven't manage to find nor derive an expression for $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$ in terms of $\cos(\theta)$. How would one proceed?

Extending the question, is there a general way to express $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{k}\right)$ in terms of $\cos(\theta)$? (with $k\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Maybe you have misead $\pi$ for $\theta$? Please check again your proposal for closure.

Comment: @the_candyman, sorry I did not mean to use $x$, it must be late...

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I don't think it is a duplicate, I am looking for general $\theta$ and not only $\pi$.

Comment: No, @user, I have not.  The linked question asks for one to find a formula for $\sin(3a)$ in terms of $\cos(a)$ and $\sin(a)$, **then** to use that formula to obtain the value of $\sin(\pi/3)$.  But the method for obtaining the formula $\sin(3a)$ is nearly identical to that for $\cos(3a)$, which is what is required here.

Comment: @XanderHenderson To me, it seems not a duplicate! Anyway you are of course more expert than me in closure!

Comment: There is also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432254), which seems to address the current (after editing) version of the current question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm sure I've already seen something more specific and strictly related. Maybe it has been deleted? I'll take a look for it.

Comment: And there is also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442546/468350), which discusses the derivation of triple angle formulae.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It is not strictly a duplicate, maybe it covers also this one but I wouldn't classify it as a duplicate. I'm sure there is some other more fitting question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What about this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1242286/505767)? This also seems cover this OP.

Comment: @user Note that the [first answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/432263/446262) provides a complete answer to this question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I noticed that. Indeed I claim that it covers it but it is not a duplicate. Moreover note that the asker here is asking also for a more general extension: "is there a general way to express $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{k}\right)$ in terms of $\cos(\theta)$? (with $k\in\mathbb{N}$)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To express $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{3}\right)$ in terms of $\cos \theta$ we can use [Triple-angle formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Triple-angle_formulae)

$$\cos (3\theta) = 4 \cos^3\theta - 3 \cos\theta$$

but we need to solve a cubic equation.

Refer also to

- [Find a formula for $\sin(3a)$ and use to calculate $\sin(π/3)$ and $\cos(π/3)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1196178/505767)
- [Is there anything like “cubic formula”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2052616/505767)

---

**Edit**

For the more general issue we can refer to [Chebyshev method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Chebyshev_method)

$$\cos(n\theta ) = 2  \cos \theta \cdot \cos((n-1)\theta) − \cos((n-2)\theta)$$

Comment: In fact, this identity is one way to solve cubic equations. To avoid circularity in this context, we'll need another, Cardano's method.

Comment: @J.G. Yes indeed we need to solve the cubic equation by Cardano's method.

Comment: As you noted above, [the asker here is asking for a more general extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455055/how-to-express-cos-left-frac-theta3-right-in-terms-of-cos-theta#comment7102541_3455055).  You have not addressed this issue at all.  Will you be editing your answer to address this?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes you are right, I add something also on that. Thanks

Comment: @Ulysse By  Chebyshev method once we know $\cos \theta$ we can easily find $\cos (n\theta)$ but for the inverse problem, yes in general we need to solve a polynomial of order $n$. That's not a trivial problem.